# How to create no data alerts in grafana multidimensional alerts

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am creating a multidimensional alert for a group of windows hosts. The goal is to alert if the hosts do not report anymore(no data alert).
Based on [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/unified-alerting/alerting-rules/create-grafana-managed-rule/) documentation, i can filter for every host the metrics, but when setting the alert condition, to alert in case of no data, nothing happens, eventhough the host is not reporting. The metrics are showing only the reporting hosts. Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Created a new alert, by the following query, which will show the targets which are not generating metritcs (no data/null):

```
up{environment="prod"} == 0
```